# git pull: fatal: refusing to merge unrelated histories

Tags: git, github

Description:
I have a remote repository with his data. I have a local repository with his data.

I want to clone/pull the data from my remote repo to my local repo without changing the local repo folder structure.

Or I want to push my local repo to my remote repo with the local repo structure without altering the remote repo folder structure. I want to keep my local repo for future pushing.

> 1. git init [ok] Output: Initialized empty Git repository in [...]
> 2. git add . [ok]
> 3. git commit -m "first commit" [ok] Output:  9 files changed, 168 insertions(+) [...]
> 4. git remote add origin https://github.com/Mi7ai/Spring.git [ok]
> 5. git remote -v [ok] Output: origin  https://github.com/Mi7ai/Spring.git (fetch) origin  https://github.com/Mi7ai/Spring.git (push)
> 6. git push origin master [warning] Output: hint: Updates were rejected because the remote contains work that you do [...]. You may want to first integrate the remote changes hint: (e.g., 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
> 7. git pull origin master [warning] Output:  * branch  master     -> FETCH_HEAD
>    fatal: refusing to merge unrelated histories

I have read that *--allow unrelated histories* is not the right way to do it.

How should I achieve what I want?

OS: Windows 10

Thanks.

Comment: Why not simply clone the remote, make the changes you want, then commit and push back to the remote?

Comment: @Thomas because I want to keep the remote repo with all commits. I want a new folder structure pushed to the remote, which is the one from my local repo. Basically I want a new local folder as the new repo.

Comment: Are you trying to have two separate version of it? If so, then a clean branch may be the way to go. The standard add/commit/push/pull will not work here since your remote `master/main` has history that does not exists locally.

Comment: @astrochun I worked with Intellij and did every repo management from the IDE. Now I switched to Eclipse and want to do it manually within Eclipse folder structure. No, I don't want two separate versions.

Comment: @Mi7ai If you're trying to do it separately in with another IDE then those are two separate histories.  But you say you want the two to merge. Well that's not really possible within the same repo. I recommend that you `git clone` the repo into another path. Not the same one that you're working in. Then migrate the files over to that path and `git add FILE`, `git commit -m "message"` `git push`.